# Tracking Location Mapbox Recycle code from Java to Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have used mapbox sdk to show map to user but when i add TRacking function.
But seem it can't run

```
 public void OnStyleLoaded(Style p0)     
   {
            MainActivity.style = p0;
            LocationComponent locationComponent =MainActivity.mapboxMap.LocationComponent;

           locationComponent.ActivateLocationComponent(LocationComponentActivationOptions.InvokeBuilder(this.Activity,MainActivity.style).Build());
            locationComponent.ForceLocationUpdate(locationComponent.LastKnownLocation);

            // Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.LocationComponentEnabled=true;

            // Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.CameraMode=CameraMode.TRACKING;

            // Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.RenderMode=RenderMode.COMPASS;

   MainActivity.mapboxMap.AddOnMapClickListener(this);
```

}

It haven't any error but when use nothing happen in map!

Answer (score 0):

It seem to you can't get last location know.You need to init ILocationEngine class for this.And seem to you need to ask for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permisson for this.